# Unable to copy data from one redis server to another

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, distributed-caching, redis-cluster

I have **redis db** in **stage** whose data **I want to copy** in **dev** server. I tried copying data using **SLAVEOF** command as well as **SAVE** command.

Both stage and dev are **clustered redis servers**.

Both commands are giving errors:

#### SLAVEOF:

```sh
# running in dev server
host-dev.redis.db:6379> SLAVEOF host-stage.redis.db 6379
(error) ERR unknown command `SLAVEOF`, with args beginning with: `host-dev.redis.db`, `6379`,
```

#### SAVE

```sh
# running in stage server
host-stage.redis.db:6379> SAVE
(error) ERR unknown command `SAVE`, with args beginning with:
```

Am I missing something with these commands in the case of clustered redis servers? Or these errors are due to some missing config?

Comment: Where does dev server hosted? aws elasticache ?